How to verify vc_redist.x64.exe with osslsigncode?
osslsigncode verify VirtualBox-7.1.0-164728-Win.exe: Functional.
osslsigncode verify vc_redist.x64.exe: Broken.
Why? How to fix?
Full logs below.
Debian 12.

Functional:
osslsigncode verify VirtualBox-7.1.0-164728-Win.exe

Current PE checksum   : 0698F8DE
Calculated PE checksum: 0698F8DE

Signature Index: 0  (Primary Signature)
Message digest algorithm  : SHA256
Current message digest    : 219D775E1F63FD2734FDB97D7EE67A17488B0E18B9A294114F7E17D8834B597F 
Calculated message digest : 219D775E1F63FD2734FDB97D7EE67A17488B0E18B9A294114F7E17D8834B597F 

Signer's certificate:
        Signer #0:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Redwood City/O=Oracle America, Inc./CN=Oracle America, Inc.
                Issuer : /C=US/O=DigiCert, Inc./CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1
                Serial : 060E2F8F9E1B8BE518D5FE2B69CFCCB1
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Mar  9 00:00:00 2023 GMT
                        notAfter : Mar 11 23:59:59 2025 GMT

Number of certificates: 2
        Signer #0:
                Subject: /C=US/O=DigiCert, Inc./CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1
                Issuer : /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Trusted Root G4
                Serial : 08AD40B260D29C4C9F5ECDA9BD93AED9
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Apr 29 00:00:00 2021 GMT
                        notAfter : Apr 28 23:59:59 2036 GMT
        ------------------
        Signer #1:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Redwood City/O=Oracle America, Inc./CN=Oracle America, Inc.
                Issuer : /C=US/O=DigiCert, Inc./CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1
                Serial : 060E2F8F9E1B8BE518D5FE2B69CFCCB1
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Mar  9 00:00:00 2023 GMT
                        notAfter : Mar 11 23:59:59 2025 GMT

Authenticated attributes:
        Message digest algorithm: SHA256
        Message digest: 780A2C240E94C6A520FBA4EBA7ADC02D5DB11B0F223CD3F202A4F11A56F73A7A 
        Signing time: N/A
        Microsoft Individual Code Signing purpose

The signature is timestamped: Sep  6 22:12:04 2024 GMT
Hash Algorithm: sha256
Timestamp Verified by:
                Issuer : /C=US/O=DigiCert, Inc./CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 RSA4096 SHA256 TimeStamping CA
                Serial : 0544AFF3949D0839A6BFDB3F5FE56116

CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TSA's certificates file: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CRL distribution point: http://crl3.digicert.com/DigiCertTrustedG4CodeSigningRSA4096SHA3842021CA1.crl
TSA's CRL distribution point: http://crl3.digicert.com/DigiCertTrustedG4RSA4096SHA256TimeStampingCA.crl

Timestamp Server Signature verification: ok
Signature verification time: Sep  6 22:12:04 2024 GMT
Signature verification: ok

Number of verified signatures: 1
Succeeded


Broken:
osslsigncode verify vc_redist.x64.exe

Current PE checksum   : 0187CD76
Calculated PE checksum: 0187CD76

Signature Index: 0  (Primary Signature)
Message digest algorithm  : SHA256
Current message digest    : 870E96D39FD03180C74AE4BCC1C4B6203AF36AABDAC37210773C127F37393036 
Calculated message digest : 870E96D39FD03180C74AE4BCC1C4B6203AF36AABDAC37210773C127F37393036 

Signer's certificate:
        Signer #0:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2011
                Serial : 3300000403BDD5955D0F3B18AD000000000403
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Sep 12 20:11:13 2024 GMT
                        notAfter : Sep 11 20:11:13 2025 GMT

Number of certificates: 2
        Signer #0:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Corporation
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2011
                Serial : 3300000403BDD5955D0F3B18AD000000000403
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Sep 12 20:11:13 2024 GMT
                        notAfter : Sep 11 20:11:13 2025 GMT
        ------------------
        Signer #1:
                Subject: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2011
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011
                Serial : 610E90D2000000000003
                Certificate expiration date:
                        notBefore : Jul  8 20:59:09 2011 GMT
                        notAfter : Jul  8 21:09:09 2026 GMT

Authenticated attributes:
        Message digest algorithm: SHA256
        Message digest: C21A9171ECEC5F60ADFB1DDFF81B447D8B810D6A893F604E7C3D50849E3719DD 
        Signing time: N/A
        Microsoft Individual Code Signing purpose
        URL description: http://www.microsoft.com
        Text description: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.42.34433

The signature is timestamped: Oct 29 12:03:40 2024 GMT
Hash Algorithm: sha256
Timestamp Verified by:
                Issuer : /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010
                Serial : 33000001F91F678D75ABA4F1B10001000001F9

CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TSA's certificates file: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CRL distribution point: http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicCodSigPCA2011_2011-07-08.crl

CMS_verify error
4049E3FCAC7E0000:error:17000064:CMS routines:cms_signerinfo_verify_cert:certificate verify error:../crypto/cms/cms_smime.c:289:Verify error: unable to get local issuer certificate
Timestamp Server Signature verification: failed

PKCS7_verify error
4049E3FCAC7E0000:error:10800075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:../crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:295:Verify error: unable to get local issuer certificate
Signature verification: failed

Number of verified signatures: 1
Failed
zsh: exit 1     osslsigncode verify vc_redist.x64.exe


It would be worth reporting an issue about this to get an accurate answer (and, if it turns out to be a bug in osslsigncode, hopefully get it fixed).
